# Computational complexity depending on two variables

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm and it is mainly composed of k-NN , followed by a computation involving finding permutations, followed by some for loops. Line by line, my computational complexity is :

```
O(n) - for k-NN
O(2^k) - for a part that computes singlets, pairs, triplets, etc.
O(k!) - for a part that deals with combinatorics.
O(k*k!) - for the final part.
```

`K` here is a parameter that can be chosen by the user, in general it is somewhat small (10-100). `n` is the number of examples in my dataset, and this can get very large.

What is the overall complexity of my algorithm? Is it simply `O(n)` ?

Comment: `O(k*k!)` is much larger than `O(k)`, but since you said that `k` is fixed and relatively small, the `O(n)` term is the only term which will keep growing as the sample size becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: The algorithm is `O(N)` in an academic sense. But a large `k` here is going to dominate the `n` if you have a term of O(k * k!).  So in a practical sense whatever step is `O(k * k!) is going to be where optimization should occur, if of course it is at all possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `k <= 100`, `f(k) = O(1)` for every function `f`.
In your case, there is a function `f` such that the overall time is `O(n + f(k))`, so it is `O(n)`

Comment: If k is relevant to me, say that k could grow as large as it wants, just like n, can I then say that my complexity is O(n + k!) ?

Comment: Almost, it's `O(n + (k+1)!)`. as both `k*k!` and `2^k` and `k!` are in `O((k+1)!)`, the overall time is bounded by `O(n+(k+1)!)`